# Writing testbench in Modelsim

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I am trying to write a test bench in verilog in modelsim. I have written the code for test bench as well as for module under test. But while compiling it, i am getting a error saying that compilation failed .
So do we have to write the test bench code in separate module and also the same for the module under test?

```
//Writing a test bench
module test_bench;
wire w1,w2,w3;
xyz(w1,w2,w3);
test_xyz(w1,w2,w3);
endmodule;
```

//Now we will define the modules which we have intsantiated in the testbench       module

//Defining the module xyz

```
module xyz(f,A,B);
input A,B;
output f;
nor(f,A,B);
endmodule;

//Defining the test module which we are going to apply to the module xyz

module test_xyz(f,A,B); 
input f;
output A,B;
initial 
begin 
$monitor ($time ,"A=%b","B=%b", "f=%b",A,B,f);
#10 A=0;B=0;
#10 A=1;B=0;
#10 A=1;B=1;
#10 $finish ;
end
endmodule;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`endmodule` does not require a semicolon.

Instances should have instance names:

```
module test_bench;
  wire          w1,w2,w3;
  xyz      dut (w1,w2,w3);
  test_xyz test(w1,w2,w3);
endmodule
```

If your going to drive signals from an initial or alwys block, they need to be `reg` not `wire` in the localscope*.

```
module test_xyz(f,A,B); 
  input f;
  output reg A,B; //A B are regs
```

*localscope : where the wire is being driven it is a reg but the output of a module drives a wire. Verilog types do not cross port boundaries.

Example on [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Wnz).